# Optimal Parry/Riposte window

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have noticed that in some circumstances, when you parry and riposte an enemy, sometimes you do more damage than others.

For example, on either the Alonne knights in the Iron Keep, or the Syan Soldiers in the Drangleic Castle, when using the Greatsword, the "upward sweep" riposte animation seems to either cause one or two hits during the animation. The most concrete evidence of this is I may need to either parry/riposte them, and then hit them once more after they get up, *or* I just parry/riposte once.

I have attempted to reproduce this effectively, but to no avail.

Does anyone know what might cause this?

**Note -** I am referring to the console version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was known as a phantom parry, it happened when walking backwards before doing the riposte attack and attacking just before leaving the riposte range. This affected multiple, but not all weapons (The normal dagger is an example for a weapon it was often used for).

The game would essentially ad a normal rb/r1 attack to the riposte, adding to the overall damage.

I thought it was fixed a while ago though.

For more information on the technical stuff check the video 
"Dark Souls 2: Technique - Phantom Ripostes & Backstabs"
on youtube.

Comment: This does sound viable, because there was no significant window or other input that could signal a successful "double parry" or "phantom parry" as you put it, other than possibly re-arranging myself. All that would happen is in one instance, I would deal the normal amount of damage, and in another, seemingly random occurrence, there would be a second amount of damage, dealt almost a split second after the first initial attack. At first I thought it was a timing thing, but now I'm not so sure...

Comment: In my experience it has nothing to do with timing.
The non-riposte (most likely lower) damage instance is just a normal hit without an animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for Parry frame data, [the fextralife wiki has got a nice summary](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Parry+Frame+Data).

If you're looking for term of hits: I know from experience that some weapons apply 2 hits, and other weapons apply only 1. The animation / amount of hits may differ from ripostes and backstabs.

Comment: To be honest, while detailed, the information given in the wiki makes little sense to me. Could you explain it a bit? Maybe give an example of what this means?

Comment: As for the weapons that apply 2 hits, I do know what you mean, (for example the dagger deals 2 hits during a backstab). However that's not really what I was referring to :)

Comment: @InfernoIV Does this also count for Dark Souls 1? Quite interesting...

Comment: @FinnRayment This also counts for Dark Souls 1

Comment: @InfernoIV Great! After reading this, can't wait to double damage everyone! :P